Is it correct to say "I don't think I have a good sensibility towards art"?
I think "sensibility" already included the "art" part. So I'm not sure if I use "towards art" correctly in this situation.

What do you mean by "good sensibility"? Ability to discern what is good and bad? A positive attitude? A strong emotional response? Something else?

You can have a “discerning eye” or "a good eye”  for art, the negative form would suggest the speaker is unable to discern (tell) good art from bad.

@Mari-LouA I can use the phrase for "literature", can't I? Also, can I use it for things which are not directly related to using eyes?

@anIELTSlearner which phrase? Mine or the OP's? If it's mine, then "a good eye for literature/poetry" (etc)  also works. I might say "I know a good book when I see it"

Someone can have good taste in music, clothes, books etc. Or (it's just come to me) a good ear for music.

Thank you. What about when I can tell if a book is good or bad in general, but I suck at understanding the implied meaning behind the lines of a poetry or a piece of writing when they're too deep, is there a word or phrase for it? I would say "being bad at literary appreciation", but it's simply a guess.

Excuse me for being a bit harsh, but have you really considered: being sensitive to something (like art or music)? People's sensitivity to things can differ widely.

It is very frustrating to try and explain misuse to someone who then ignores it. I tried to keep the register but using sensitivity, which is usual in these contexts rather than providing a lower register.

Regardless of the strict grammar / semantics, I don't think I have a good sensibility towards art isn't remotely idiomatic.
Maybe I don't think I have a good sense of art would be better, but the idiomatic standard in English is...

I don't know much about art [but I know what I like].

That's a link to hundreds of published written instances of at least the first six words. Possibly as many as half of which continue with something along the lines of my ...but... clause.

Regardless or because of??

If you think it's because of, I'm not gonna argue with you. But I knew exactly what I meant and why when I wrote regardless of. Ditto for the fact that I didn't want to pronounce on either the syntax or the semantics of the non-idiomatic text. What's the point of analyzing an utterance that only a non-native speaker would be likely to produce?

I really do not know how you can say the idiomatic standard is [some sentence] and basically ignore the OP. There are also hundreds of hits for have sensitivity to art. https://app.ludwig.guru/s/sensitivity+to+art

I can say it because when I cut and paste the OP's actual text into a Google Books search, I get:  No results found for "good sensibility towards art"

Of course it isn't idiomatic. No one is disputing that. If I needed Google Books for that, I'd be in real trouble.

"a good sensibility towards art" is not idiomatic English.
An informal way of saying that in American English (possibly in British English as well) is to use the phrase "a feel for".

I don't have a feel for art.

It means that you don't really understand it, or respond to it emotionally; you don't see what others find so beautiful or so moving or so excellent about it.

I don't have a feel for poetry.
I don't have a feel for {classical, rap, disco, punk, folk, whatever} music.


Right, it is not idiomatic. I really don't get why no one is calling out this use of sensibility when sensitivity is the usual collocation.

@Lambie I've seen both.  "She has an artist's sensibility". "Some readers are insensitive to nuance."

Yes, sure, but in everyday conversation, we'd say sensitive to.

No, sensibility doesn't only refer to your feelings about the arts. Have you checked the meaning in more than one online dictionary?
Also, we don't talk about having a 'good' or 'bad' sensibility, but about how much of it we have. So you could say that you don't think you have a great deal of sensibility towards art.

I don't have much sensitivity to art.
idiom: to be sensitive to/about an art form.
good does not collocate well semantically with sensibility or sensitivity. Adjectives like much, not much, strong, great etc. are better.
I have much ill will towards her.
Otherwise, you risk sounding like Jane Austen: Sense and Sensibility
See the definition of sensitivity and sensitivity in Merriam Webter:
sensibility
See an article about this subject here:
Exposure to Better and Poorer Art
And from ludwig.guru, these sentences:
Greater sensitivity to art, she added, makes artists who work as guards especially careful about protecting it.
2
The New York Times - Arts
Neither physical demonstrativeness nor sensitivity to art was considered a desirable trait by the rest of his family.
3
The New Yorker
· View the work online Artist: Michelangelo Buonarroti (1475-1564), born in Tuscany and educated in Florence, undertook his most ambitious work in Rome for Julius II, a warrior pope whose terrible temper did not exclude a sensitivity to art.
In two tasks designed to assess sensitivity to visual art and emotional sounds, we tested 13 individuals previously identified as specific musical anhedonics, together with two more groups with average (musical hedonic, HDN) and high (musical hyperhedonics, HHDN) sensitivity to experience reward from music.
1
Progress in Brain Research

Disregard the downvotes. They are mistaken. [Grrrh]
